# How to get the name of the running application in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uiapplication

If the application name under the icon on the home screen is "My Awesome App" how do you get that string within the application at runtime?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

I’d try

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
```

although presumably you know your own app’s name and can just use it…

Comment: This works, although the constant doesn't exist. Guessing it is @"CFBundleDisplayName". I don't want to hard code the app name in as the code I'm writing may get used in other apps.

Comment: Ah, you're right, there's no constant (I copied some existing code that grabbed a different key). The raw string should be fine though.

Comment: This worked for me after I added the `Bundle display name` property in my `Info.plist` file.

Comment: not CFBundleDisplayName but CFBundleName. Do not be deceived

Comment: Well it depends. Check the documentation for CFBundleDisplayName.

Comment: Thanks to @pasql, I was missing Bundle display name property in my Info.plist, for this I was getting null from bundle

Answer (score 30):

## Swift 3 & 4

```
Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleName") as? String ?? ""
Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleDisplayName") as? String ?? ""
```

## Swift 2.2

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleName")
NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleDisplayName")
```

### More about 'CFBundleName' and 'CFBundleDisplayName'

The following is from [Apple's documentation on
Core Foundation Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-110725)

**CFBundleName**, “Bundle name”, The short name of the bundle; not intended to be seen by the user. See [CFBundleName](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-109585) for details. (Recommended, Localizable)

**CFBundleDisplayName**, “Bundle display name”, The user-visible name of the bundle; used by Siri and visible on the Home screen in iOS. See [CFBundleDisplayName](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-110725) for details. (Required, Localizable)

Comment: The documentation says that CFBundleDisplayName is a required key… also, it says CFBundleName is the “short name of the bundle; not intended to be seen by the user.”

Comment: Thank you @DavidDunham! I updated the text in my answer under "More about 'CFBundleName' and 'CFBundleDisplayName'" to match Apple's current documentation.

Comment: Curiosity: What's the point of using this code, if it might be nil and a default value should be provided? Why not just use that value?

Answer (score 19):

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleName"];
```

Answer (score 14):

Just because I love the Xcode 4.5 new way to get an array item.  :)

```
- (NSString*)project_getAppName {
    return NSBundle.mainBundle.infoDictionary[@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
}
```

Comment: what is this sorcery? I didn't know you could do it like this.

Comment: Does this exist in Swft?

Answer (score 8):

For Xamarin.iOS use:

```cs
return ((NSString)NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary["CFBundleName"]).ToString();
```

Answer (score 8):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

// work for iOS and MacOSX and ~23 times faster than get name from bundle
NSString *app = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:getprogname()];
```

Comment: Useful too if you're writing a command-line tool that isn't in a bundle structure or doesn't have an Info.plist file to populate infoDictionary.

Answer (score 6):

### **Swift 3, 4, & 5**

```
let appName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3/4

```
let appName =  Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: kCFBundleNameKey as String) as? String
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString* applicationName = [entry objectForKey:(id)kCGWindowOwnerName];
```

[Here is a good post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2628511/59017) with examples of what you are looking for. The OP didn't accept anything, which is unfortunate, but the answers are useful.

Comment: Thanks, some great information in that post. Prefer the one liner in Davids answer though ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

**Attention**:

If you do a `localizations` in your app, you should use the blew code to get the true localized display name:

```
Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleName") as? String ?? ""
Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleDisplayName") as? String ?? ""
```

**rather than**:

```
Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: kCFBundleNameKey as String) as? String
```