# Application name on UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I would like to put application name on UILabel. 
I have found how to put App version or App build using `<<APP_VERSION>>` or `<<APP_BUILD>>`. I would like also to put the application name in the same way, is there any something like `<<APP_NAME>>` in Xcode?
I have two different build targets in the project, each with different app name.

Comment: Take a look at this question, maybe it's what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320860/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-running-application-in-ios

Comment: I thought about ` <<>> ` option, as I can use it without any line of code. But ` [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"]; ` is also acceptable to include in the code. Thanks!

Comment: i have added an answer to make it easier. You should take a look ;)

Comment: The application name cannot be changed at runtime so what's wrong with using a simple literal (localized) string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want use it without any line of code.

First, define APP_NAME

```
#define APP_NAME  [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"]
```

And use APP_NAME as a `NSString` value

```
NSLog(@"%@", APP_NAME);
```